# OBC DA FIR Filter Implementation

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, dsp-core

I understand the theory of Distributed Arithmetic and its application in FIR Filter implementation to avoid the excessive power consumption in the multiplication operations

But a question here, when I try to solve it numerically in a paper, it gets a correct answer when I do the following:

let $j=0$ LSB and $j=5$ MSB;
$Q_{\text{init}} + y_0 + y_1 x 2 + y_2 x 4 + y_3 x 8 + y_4 x 16 - y_5 x 32 $

But when I make just divide by 2, the answer was wrong as the following

$$\{  [ (Q_{\text{init}} + y_0) / 2] + y_1  \}/2 \ldots.$$

So, how can I do the shift right by 1 (divide by 2) implementation numerically ?

[image]

Comment: I'm having a really hard time reading your formulas; I think what you wrote as `x 2`, `x 4` … is what you'd denote as `x(2)`, `x(4)`… in your Figure 3, right?

Comment: removing the [tag:image-processing] and [tag:adaptive-filters] tags, as unrelated to the question.